# Как правильно делать возврат html-страницы из контроллера. И как протестировать этот возврат?

Tags: java, spring, maven

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String genIndex() {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

Файл *index.html* лежит в директории:

```
resources/templates/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

подключаем

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Так как у вас файл уже лежит в resources/templates. тогда просто можно написать

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Если не добавить расширение .html , то работает только если запустить проект в IntelliJ IDEA, а вот если взять збилденный .jar запустить - то ошибка 500, и не возвращает index.html(

Answer (score 0):

Сделал

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String getIndex() {
    return "index";
}
```

Но при этом добавил в **application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Все работает. Из IDEA и через деплой)Еще бы узнать, как это тестировать (и надо ли) через JUnit4